# Gastric Bypass Surgery and Creatine/HMB

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, supplements, creatine

I have had gastric bypass WLS earlier in the year, and now with the surgeon's encouragement, I have started weight training to preserve lean body mass. It's going well so far, and after two months, I'm about to move away from the weight machine circuit to the free-weight room. I've been reading about HMB and Creatine, and believe they can help me in my goal to preserve (or even gain!) lean mass in the form of muscle.

What is the best way to take creatine for someone without a full-size stomach? I can't gulp down a lot of fluid all at once, so the powder is tricky, and I'm concerned the capsules won't digest properly. This is also my concern with HMB - can someone with WLS digest the capsules properly?

Also, I can't handle a lot of sugar - fruit juice and other sweets causes temporary but severe side effects (dizziness, nausea, intestinal distress, elevated BP, etc) plus it undermines my weight loss and needed lifestyle change to keep it off. I can and do eat fresh fruit and unsweetened applesauce daily. Is that enough take creatine effectively?

Comment: You do need to drink lots of water with creatine, but you don't have to do it all at once.

Comment: @BerinLoritsch - I sip constantly, and get plenty of hydration. Water isn't the issue, it's the powder. It winds up in a lump at the bottom, as I can't drink it fast enough.

Comment: About how much can you drink at a time?  You might be able to spread the doses throughout the day.

Comment: I'd recommend you speak with your surgeon they'd probably be able to give better advice than random internet strangers.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - He'd heard of creatine, didn't see how it could hurt anything, but didn't know how I should take it. Not his specialty. Hence internet strangers.

Answer (score -1):

Some supplement manufacturers make a chewable creatine product - I purchased GNC's Creatine Complex Chew. It *is* pretty high in calories and carbs for a supplement (mostly starches), but it's low in sugar and almost fat-free. Each chew has 1000mg creatine, and they recommend three chews per serving. It tastes like a grainy and bitter lemon-flavored tootsie roll, and is small enough and digestible enough where it's easy for anyone with WLS to take over the course of the day.

Comment: -1 The OP has under gone gastric bypass, so its a safe bet to say they are trying to manage their weight and are on a calorie restricted diet. A high calorie chew, regardless of creatine content, is probably not suitable for them.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - I *am* the OP, answering my own question. :D It's 30 calories per serving - which is more than my chewable multi-vitamin and calcium chew, but not exactly an indulgence.